# Why is it called a group action?

Tags: terminology, abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

A group action has two laws which roughly correspond to associativity and identity

$
\phi : (G : \textrm{Group}) \times (S : \textrm{Set}) \rightarrow S \\
\forall a, b : G . \forall c : S. \phi(a,\phi(b, c)) = \phi(a \cdot b, c) \\
\forall a : S. \phi (1,a) = a
$

Looking at this definition there's nothing very "group"-like about it.  There's no law about inverses or cancellation.  It would seem that "monoidal-action" would be a more sensible name since these laws line up nicely with the monoid laws.

Where does the term "group action" come from?  What context leads to the word "group" in its name?

Comment: There are few strange things here, including the additive notation for the binary and the usage of colon instead of $\in$. Otherwise, it's the standard definition of a group action.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I choose additive here to avoid any collision with the $\times$ operator used in the type of $\phi$.  But the colon is what I am generally accustomed to,  I could change it to $\in$ if it really is confusing.

Comment: It's common to denote the binary operation in groups simply $ab$ (not $a\times b$!). I've never seen colon used instead of $\in$: Where did you find it? The most common meaning of colon in set theory is to denote the expression "such that."

Comment: @MoisheKohan I like to avoid concatenation for the sake of clarity as well because it's conventional to denote *everything* in group theory with it including this $\phi$ operator.  It is genuinely a pretty confusing way to do things and $+$ is common enough.  Colon commonly denotes "Is of type" esp. in type theory ([wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colon_(punctuation)#Mathematics_and_logic)), you can see [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupSet.html) when defining group set they use a mix of both colon and $\in$.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic + is usually reserved for an Abelian group, so to use it here overstates the case. Ordinary group operation is usually notated by simple concatenation.

Comment: I've used $\cdot$ now.  I think this is nice and unambiguous, while not being $+$.

Comment: I have not heard it called a "group set".  Instead, I have heard it called a "group action".  We say the group $G$ acts on the set $S$.  We my say that $(S,\phi)$ is a "$G$-space" (or maybe a "$G$-set).

Comment: "A group set is a set whose elements are acted on by a group", [MathWorld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupSet.html). "Group" is there simply because it acts on the set, the axioms are for action and are not supposed to imitate group axioms.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar A quick search shows that you are correct that this is also called a group action.  In fact I feel as if I have dim memories of this being the term used in my Galois theory textbook.  However be careful $G$-set is a separate term, a $G$-set is a group set without the identity law present here. ($G$ space also seems to be a term in topology, but I've never seen it so I will defer on that)

Comment: Regardless of what “MathWorld” says, I have never seen the term group set before. I think it is obscure terminology, definitely not standard. But $G$-set is standard. In any case, I think the term “group action” for the way a *group* moves elements of a set around is quite reasonable: the elements of the group act as permutations of the set in a way that makes composition of permutations compatible with the group law. It’s unclear why you find the term group action so unintuitive.

Comment: @KCd I find it unintuitive for the reasons stated in the question.  The action seems more monoidal than group.  It has two laws which mirror the monoid laws and it doesn't directly interact with the third law groups have.  I think the history of this term would be interesting.  Since groups as a concept are older than monoids.

Comment: There is no need for a separate inverse axiom because it holds automatically; writing $\overline\phi(a)$ for $\phi(a, \cdot)$, we have that $\overline\phi(a) \circ \overline\phi(a^{-1}) = \overline\phi(a a^{-1}) = \overline\phi(1) = 1$ for all $a$, and applying to $a^{-1}$ shows that $\overline\phi(a^{-1}) = \overline\phi(a)^{-1}$.

Comment: Sometimes when you define a concept by multiple properties, it turns out one property is actually a consequence of the others, so people may *drop* that condition in the definition.  Of course we *want* the action of the group to behave well with respect to inverses, but since that follows from the other properties it is standard not to include that property in the definition of a group action.  Are you bothered that a group homomorphism $f \colon G \to H$ is not *defined* to send the identity to the identity or inverse to inverses, as that makes it seem not group-like?

Comment: What difference does it make that "action seems more monoidal than group"? "Group" in "group action" does not refer to what the action is like, it refers to the action being *by* a group. Lie algebra action is even less Lie algebra like. The history may be interesting, but it is irrelevant to your particular issue.

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, the notion of an action is not particularly attached to that of a group. You can have actions from a more complex mathematical gadget like Lie algebra actions or ring actions or a simpler one, like a monoid or a semigroup.

The group action is historically the most prominant one and hence the notion of an action is attached to that particular kind of action. For example, building an associated vector bundle, such as the adjoint bundle in Yang-Mills, requires a group action.

Answer (score 2):

What you define **is** monoid action. A group must act by permutations and the inverse element must act as inverse permutation. The second condition follows from the first and your two laws. Because the product of permutations corresponding to $a$ and $a^{-1}$ must be the identity permutation.